# Determine which pixels of QImage were changed while painting on it with QPainter

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, qimage

I have class `Paintable` that is able to paint itself with `QPainter` provided as an argument:

```
class Paintable
{
public:
    virtual void paint(QPainter*) = 0;
};
```

Instances of this class are being painted on a single QImage:

```
QImage paint(const std::vector<Paintable*>& paintables) {
    QImage result;
    QPainter p(&result);
    for(int i = 0; i < paintables.size(); ++i) {
        paintables[i]->paint(&p);
    }
    return result;
}
```

What I want to achieve is that function `paint` could also form a matrix of size equal to `result` image size in which each cell contains a pointer to `Paintable` which has drawn corresponding pixel in `result` image (something like z-buffer).

It could be achieved easily if draw methods of `QPainter` somehow let me know of which pixels of `QPaintDevice` were changed during last draw operation. Any ideas of how to do it? Should I create class derived from `QPaintDevice` or `QPaintEngine`?

I am using Qt 4.6.4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps instead of having all your Paintables paint onto the same QImage, have each one paint onto a temporary blank QImage -- i.e. a QImage with all pixels set to RGBA=(0,0,0,0).  That way, after a given Paintable's paint() method returns, you know that any pixels in the QImage that are now non-transparent must have been painted by that Paintable object.  You could then update your own z-buffer like data-structure based on that information, and then drawImage() the QImage over to a separate "accumulation QImage" (assuming you also want the composited result), clear the temporary QImage again, and repeat as necessary.

Comment: This is the first idea that has came to me too. But I guess such solution would give a huge overhead. For high resolution result image analysing each temporary image might take much time.

But if QPainter or QImage could provide just a little bit more information about painting with/on them, there would be no overhead.

Comment: If you can assign each Paintable its own unique color, and guarantee that it will only paint in that one color, then you could have them all paint to the same QImage and use a QColor->Paintable map at the end to get your results from the pixels... dunno if that's a reasonable restriction though.

Comment: ... also if you did need multiple colors, you could do two passes; one for single-color-per-Paintable "z-buffer painting" (as described in the previous comment) and then a second pass to a second QImage with the actual colors enabled.